# Google maps over https

Tags: google-maps, https

We are using Google Maps over `https` using a free maps API key. [The Google Maps API FAQ says](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial):

> The Google Maps JavaScript API and Google Static Maps API can be
>   accessed over a secure (https) connection by Google Maps API Premier
>   customers. If the Google Maps APIs are used with a free Maps API key
>   on a secure site, the browser may warn the user about non-secure
>   objects on the screen.

My understanding of the above is that the API will work anyway, but users might get a security warning. For us, however, the map will not display at all, rendering the page completely unusable.

Does anybody know if Google is blocking use of the maps API over https with free maps API keys?

Comment: I think it means you can only access google maps as HTTP, but if you use any HTTP on a page that is HTTPS you'll get the warning. If you attempt to access the maps as HTTPS then you would get nothing. That's how I'm reading the FAQ that you quoted.

Comment: I think that your understanding is correct.  Can you see if there are any errors?  You can use Firebug to check.

Answer (score 21):

As of March 15th, 2011, anyone may use the API at https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/03/maps-apis-over-ssl-now-available-to-all.html

Comment: That syntax is deprecated now.  https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodingupgrade Developers switching from v2 may be using a legacy hostname — either `maps.google.com`, or `maps-api-ssl.google.com` if using SSL. You should migrate to the new hostname: `maps.googleapis.com`. This hostname can be used both over both HTTPS and HTTP.

Answer (score 6):

From a quick look at the google maps premier site it seems like they probably are blocking it.  One of the listed features is the "ability to provide secure maps over https"

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/premier/

Okay, here is some more specific info:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#ssl

It seems like you are probably getting a blank map because you are attempting to access with https a service that is only available to premiere members

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use a protocol relative URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

After installing SSL certificate, I just had to do a simple change for everything to work.

From this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

no, google will let you display the map even if you are using free google API's over https login.

It definitely gives you a pop up box asking for a yes/no but your map will be displayed for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to work around the problem by using OpenStreetMap instead. It doesn't present a super easy solution, because OpenStreetMap's main tile server does not support HTTPS connections, however there are various things you're allowed to do with OpenStreetMap which google would never allow.

Some more discussion of this on the OpenStreetMap forum: http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=5546