# google maps GMaps Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I'm trying to use gmaps and the map doesn't work on our live site. the same code works on our dev machine. The link is

https://dentalink.co.uk/contact.html

Comment: I see the map, maybe I fixed it. take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201274/google-maps-over-https

Comment: strange issue. I can see the map from other devices e.g my iphone but not on my computer

Comment: interesting. I noticed that if access page without https then it works fine

Comment: please read the question I pointed out in my first comment, there certainly have the solution to your problem

Comment: thanks a lot. problem solved. I used https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true and it worked.